# is it possible to execute multiple operation using ternary operator

Tags: javascript

As conditional logic we use if else statement.But as there is a ternery operator ,i wonder if i can execute multiple statement using this operator? Here i have a `var index` which is initially set to `zero`.By clicking a button i execute some conditional logic using this index variable.When it reaches to a specific value  i want to reset it to its initial value and also change the button name.I was thinking is it possible using ternary operator?

currently my statement is:

```
(index<ques.length-1) ? btn.value='next' : btn.value='start quiz again';
```

i am thinking is it possible to achieve something like this.it's giving an error:

```
(index<ques.length-1) ? btn.value='next' : btn.value='start quiz again';index=0;
```

the full code below is about a simple quiz application whch shows next question on clicking a button and change the `button's value property` using ternary operator based on `index variable value`

```js
var ques=[
          {
      title:'who is the captain of bangladesh odi team?',
      option:['mashrafee','tamim','sakib','mushfic'],
      crctAns:'mashrafee'
    },
    {
      title:'who invented ac current?',
      option:['nicola tesla','tomas edison','henry ford','graham bell'],
      crctAns:'nicola tesla'
    },
    {  
      title:'who starred in "TRAINING DAY" movie?',
      option:['danzel washington','morgan freeman','lionerdo decaprio'],
      crctAns:'danzel washington'
    }
    ];
    var setQues=(function(){
    
      var index=0;
      var span=document.createElement('span');
   span.setAttribute('style','color:crimson;font-weight:20px;');
   span.setAttribute('id','myspan');
   var div=document.getElementById('mydiv');
   var btn=document.getElementById('btn');
   
  
      return function (){
      div.innerHTML='';
      span.innerHTML=ques[index].title;
      div.appendChild(span);
      (index<ques.length-1) ? btn.value='next' : btn.value='start quiz again';index=0;
      index++;
      
      
      
     
     
    }})()
    
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',setQues);
```

```css
   #mydiv{
    background:lightblue;
    border:1px solid skyblue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    box-shadow:-5px 0px  
    
 }
```

```html
<div id='mydiv' ></div>
<input type='button' value='start quiz' id='btn'>
```

Comment: i can use if but my question is about whether it is possible or not?

Comment: is index a global variable?

Comment: @NickSlash defined right above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
expr1, expr2
```

In your case:

```
(index<ques.length-1) ? btn.value='next' : (btn.value='start quiz again', index=0);
```

However, I'd argue that using the conditional operator for its side effects is not good style.

Comment: i was going to use if statement ,but it eventually came to my mind and applied it but i got an error.thanks a lot!!